# Multi item carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this working example [Multi Item Carousel](https://codepen.io/Qvatra/pen/yOvBoM) where I have 4 items next to each other (on resolution 1200px or more), and I would like to change it to 7 smaller items.

I have tried to add

```
.active > div:first-child + div + div + div + div { display:block; }
```

in the `/*lg*/` section in `css` (below line 72) and I also increased range in `JS` (line 8) like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
```

And also I added more items in html, so that I have 7

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="carousel-col">
        <div class="block yellow img-responsive"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But that did not help, it just added 1 item + 2 when slide occurs, in the next row.

What am I missing?

Comment: I have experienced some stubborn mates in this community so sometimes it can't go without it. I asked question formatted well, checked for existing solutions, I have provided a working example and I did put effort into finding a solution.

Comment: Maybe this solution helps you to fix your issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77640427/how-to-create-an-infinity-multi-item-image-carousel-touch-and-all-plain-vani/77640428#77640428

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the CSS in the `/*lg*/` section to

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .carousel-inner .active.left { left: -14.28%; }
  .carousel-inner .active.right{ left:  14.28%; }
  .carousel-inner .next        { left:  14.28%; }
  .carousel-inner .prev        { left: -14.28%; }
  .carousel-col                { width: 14.28%; }
  .active > div:first-child + div { display:block; }
  .active > div:first-child + div + div { display:block; }
  .active > div:first-child + div + div + div { display:block; }
  .active > div:first-child + div + div + div + div{ display:block; }
  .active > div:first-child + div + div + div + div + div{ display:block; }
  .active > div:first-child + div + div + div + div + div + div + div { display:block; }
}
```

And change the JavaScript range to `for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {`.

Comment: Using `.active > div:not(:first-child)` would be a much more efficient selector.

Comment: Your css here is so fragile.  Don't do this.

Comment: thank you, that works, I didn't notice changing the percentage at all. Btw, When I click right, the items are overlaying. Any idea how to get rid of it?

Comment: you can also use the general sibling selector: `.active > div:first-child ~ div {}`

Comment: @gdbj That's definitely more ideal. I was just sticking with the current format of the linked CSS.

Comment: @Ady96 What do you mean they're overlaying? I didn't see that issue. Maybe share an updated CodePen.

Comment: @John-MichaelL'Allier I have fixed it already, I forgot to add `+div`.